# How to represents a relationship in UML class diagram where relationship type depends on a field in related class?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

We have two classes namely Client and View, where View has a field *type* whose possible values are *owned* and *assigned*. Clients can have zero or more views.

Now how can i represent it in class diagram if existence of view depends whether it is *owned* or *assigned*.
*owned* views are created and owned by clients and cannot exist without existence of client, *assigned* views are assigned to them and can exist without any client

I can easily create a class named View and can extend it to have two subclasses called OwnedViews and AssignedViews, and have separate relationships defined, instead of having a field *type*, but i would like to know how to represent it in class diagram if there is a type field instead of subclassing.

Comment: Is a View can be owned by a client and assigned to another client at the same time ?

Comment: As a matter of interest, why don't/can't you create the two subtypes as you describe?  It would make the model cleaner and simpler.

Comment: "assigned" views can be assigned to any number of clients @Xaelis

Comment: Certainly doing so would make model simpler, but i just want to know whether it is possible to represent in class diagram without doing subclassing @sfinnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a constraint if you want to express that with a field.

[Composition or aggregation Class diagram http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/clientView.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/clientView.jpg)

[Copy View-Client class diagram](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_IR1eYOFpEDCthIZ4B5HRNA)

Comment: Note this allows any single View to be both owned and assigned.  That may be what you want - although it's somewhat counter-intuitive to have type='assigned' yet still have an owner.  If you want to make it mutually exclusive you'll need to extend the constraint: self.type = ViewType::OWNED implies self.owner->notEmpty() and self.clients->empty().  You'll also need an equivalent for ensuring owner is empty for assigned views.

Comment: @amitpsat you're welcome. I have add a link if you want to make a copy of this model.

Comment: agree @sfinnie, constraint has to be both ways